# $\lim_{x\rightarrow0} \frac{a\log(1+x)-\log(1+ax)}{x^2}$ without L'Hôpital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Without using L'Hôpital's, what is the following limit?

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0} \frac{a\log(1+x)-\log(1+ax)}{x^2}$$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a tour. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an edit): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959. IMPORTANT: **Tell us what you’ve tried, otherwise you have very low chance of receiving an appropriate response.**

Comment: Please learn mathjax to present your ideas better: https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwip-Yn0iPH4AhX-1jgGHRyPBTwQFnoECAIQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmath.meta.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F5020%2Fmathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference&usg=AOvVaw1zLdIXv6Cu4GY53kDgHoTt

Comment: Hint: use Taylor expansion to handle.

Comment: The Taylor expansion is a stronger tool. Why do you insist on avoiding l'Hospital rule ? It suffices to apply this rule just once.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/users/715896/ryszard-szwarc 
Yes it is powerful but out teacher has restricted us to use L hopital and Expansion

Answer (score 1):

Since $\log(1+x) = x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} + o(x^4)$, as $x\to 0$, we have

$\log(1+ax) = ax - \frac{a^2x^2}{2}+ \frac{a^3x^3}{3} + o(x^4)$.

So,

$\frac{a\log(1+x)}{x^2} = a(\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{2} + o (x))$

and

$\frac{\log(1+ax) }{x^2}= \frac{a}{x} - \frac{a^2}{2} +o(x).$

Then,

$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{a\log(1+x) - \log(1+ax)}{x^2} = \lim\limits_{x\to0}\left[(\frac{a}{x}-\frac{a}{2}+o(x)) - (\frac{a}{x} - \frac{a^2}{2} + o(x) ) \right] = \frac{a^2-a}{2}. $

Comment: [Please do not answer PSQs](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards)

Answer (score 1):

Since $\ln$ is continous function on its domain the limit asked, if exists, is $\ln L$ where
$$L=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \left(\frac{(1+x)^a}{1+ax}\right)^{\frac{1}{x^2}}.$$
Now, we compute
$$\frac{(1+x)^a}{1+ax}=(1+ax+\frac{a^2-a}{2}x^2+O(x^3))(1-ax+a^2x^2+O(x^3))=1+\frac{a^2-a}{a}x^2+O(x^3).$$
So,
$$L=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left(1+\frac{a^2-a}{2}x^2+O(x^3)\right)^{\frac{1}{x^2}}.$$
Since, $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}(1+O(x^3))^{\frac{1}{x^2}}=1$, by comparision, we can conclude that
$$L=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left(1+\frac{a^2-a}{2}x^2\right)^{\frac{1}{x^2}}.$$
Now, let $x^2=\frac{2u}{a^2-a}$ then
$$L=\left(\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}(1+u)^{\frac{1}{u}}\right)^{\frac{a^2-a}{2}}=e^\frac{a^2-a}{2}.$$
For the last equality, see [https://www2.math.uconn.edu/~hurley/math116/section4_docs/Handouts/elimit.pdf](https://www2.math.uconn.edu/%7Ehurley/math116/section4_docs/Handouts/elimit.pdf).

Hence the answer is $\ln L=\frac{a^2-a}{2}.$

Comment: [Please do not answer PSQs](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards)

Comment: He improved his text.